# Comparing files in two directories

Tags: powershell

this is what i have tried to do so far:

```
$fse = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\new1 -Filter *.txt

$fso = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\new2 -Filter *.txt | where {$fse.name -eq $_.name}

echo "output : $fso"
```

new1 directory is having files :- hi.txt, hiCopy.txt, hiCopy2.txt
new2 directory is having files :- hi.txt, hiCopy.txt

This is what i am getting :

```
PS C:\Users\prshrivastava> $fse = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path C:\new1 -Filter *.txt

PS C:\Users\prshrivastava> $fso = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\new2 -Filter *.txt | where {$fse.name -eq $_.name}

PS C:\Users\prshrivastava> echo "output : $fso"
output :
```

I'm trying to list out same files in different directory and then delete the compared directory if same files found with same match

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to compare a collection against a single item (`-eq`).

```
PS C:\> $Fse = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\new1' -Filter '*.txt' -Recurse
PS C:\> $Fse.Name

hi.txt
hiCopy.txt
hiCopy2.txt

PS C:\> $Fso = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\new2' -Filter '*.txt' -Recurse |
>> Where-Object { $Fse.Name -contains $_.Name }
PS C:\> $Fso

hi.txt
hiCopy.txt
```

[RESOURCES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)